# My ajax request return status error 405 on laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm using laravel 6. IT returns me error 405 when using external ajax.js file to handle my form.
message: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

This is my form in blade:

```
<form >
 @csrf
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Name:</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"       required="">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <strong>Email:</strong>
           <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-submit">Submit</button>
       </div>
    </form>
```

my ajax.js:

```
$(document).on('submit','#employeeSignupFrom',function (e) {
var token =  $('input[name="_token"]').attr('value')
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
    }
});
$.ajax({
    $url:'/signupemployee',
    type:'post',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    contentType:'json',
    success: function( response, textStatus, jQxhr ){
      alert('done')
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        alert('error!');
    }
});
e.preventDefault()
 })
```

the route(web.php):

```
Route::post('/signupemployee','FormsController@signupEmployee');
```

and my controller:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Illuminate\Http\Response;
  class FormsControllers extends Controller
   {
    public function signupEmployee(Request $request){
      $employeeInfo=$request->all();
      return response()->json(['alert'=>'done!']);
   }
 }
```

Comment: clear first your cache by php artisan route:cache

Comment: it cause an issue!. I can't open any pages.Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Route [signupEmployee] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\jobyob\resources\views\mainLayout\mLayout.blade.php)

Comment: what is the issue then ? you are just clearing your cache for you to be sure that you are using the correct route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove $ sign from your url:

```
//$url:'/signupemployee', <- remove $
url:'/signupemployee',
```

Second change contentType to:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

Finally your ajax should be something like this:

```js
$.ajax({
     url: '/signupemployee', //<- $ sign should deleted
     type: 'POST',
     data: data,
     contentType: 'application/json', //<- not just json
     headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
     }
})
```

Comment: tnx very much, the error 405 was because of my mistake on setting of url in ajax method. I don't know Why I have done this mistake"$url" ! and you are right contentType value is wrong. but my headers works properly @c0mmander